# Can an Element created by `document.createElement` be added to another document?

Tags: javascript, dom

Can an Element created by `document.createElement` be added to another document?

```js
   const element = document.createElement("div");
   anotherDocument.body.appendChild(element)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can, and doing so will automatically call [`anotherDocument.adoptNode(element)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/adoptNode)<sup>1</sup>.

<sub>1. Well it will call the same internal `adopt` algorithm, it won't call that method exactly.</sub>

```js
const anotherDocument = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
const element = document.createElement("div");
console.log("before", element.ownerDocument === anotherDocument, element.ownerDocument === document ); // false, true
anotherDocument.body.appendChild(element);
console.log("after", element.ownerDocument === anotherDocument, element.ownerDocument === document ); // true, false
```

Answer (score -1):

Elements created by document.createElement cannot be added to other documents. Nodes in the DOM belong to specific documents, and nodes from one document cannot be inserted into another without first cloning or importing them.

To add an element to another document, you need to create a copy using cloneNode or importNode first. You need to insert the copy into the target document using the appropriate DOM manipulation method.